# How to get number of attributes in css

Tags: javascript, css

I like to get the number of the [data-theme] attributes in the CSS with pure JS
(For replace the number 12 in my function)

Thats my CSS:

```
/*Blue*/
:root { 
  --light: #2874b2;
  --dark: #205d8e;
  --fontLight: #ffffff;
  --fontDark:  #205d8e;
}

/*Dark Blue*/
[data-theme="1"] { 
  --light:#5A7D9F;
  --dark: #3A5874;
  --fontLight: #ffffff;
  --fontDark:  #3A5874;
}

/*Pastel Blue*/
[data-theme="2"] { 
  --light:#709FC1;
  --dark:#48759E;
  --fontLight: #ffffff;
  --fontDark: #48759E;
}

/*Green*/
[data-theme="3"] { 
  --light:#00e236;
  --dark: #00b52b;
  --fontLight: #ffffff;
  --fontDark:  #00b52b;
}
...
```

Thats my function to switch the themes, but i get the value 0:

```
    function switchTheme() {
        theme++;
        var a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-theme]');
        console.log(a.length);
        if (theme > a.dataset.columns){
            theme = 1;
            localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
            return;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this to see what is inside your classes:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]

document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText
```

The arrays are not actual arrays so you cannot use [].map etc. But you can use for...loop for it.

Check them in your console.log or inspector.

Comment: You can get an *actual array* with `let actualArray = [ ...document.styleSheets ]` :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution:

```
function switchTheme() {
    theme++;
    var a = Object.keys('[data-theme]').length;
    console.log(a);
    if (theme > a){
        theme = 1;
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
        return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a style element and put those codes into there. Give id atttribute to that style element.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <style id="style">...</style>
</head>
```

JavaScript:

```
let theme = 1;
let content = document.querySelector('#style').innerText;
let match = content.match(/(\[data\-theme="\d+"\])+/g);
let count = match && match.length;

function switchTheme() {
    theme = theme >= count ? 1 : theme + 1;
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
    return theme;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One further approach is below:

```js
// a named function to handle the theme changes:
function switchTheme() {

  // caching references, first to the element (<body>) which will
  // hold the 'data-theme' attribute:
  const themedElement = document.querySelector('body'),

    // reference to the current theme-number (if set), otherwise
    // undefined:
    currentTheme = themedElement.dataset.theme,
    // if the data-themes attribute (note the slightly-different name, 
    // and the use of a plural) here we either JSON parse that attribute-
    // value (all attribute-values are strings), or we explicitly return 'null':
    possibleThemes = themedElement.dataset.themes ? JSON.parse(themedElement.dataset.themes) : null;

  // if there is no currentTheme number attributed to the <body> element (because
  // we're setting it in a later piece of code we know that it will be there if a
  // theme is currently activated):
  if (!currentTheme) {

    // we create an Array based on the document.styleSheets property, first
    // converting that iterable styleSheetList into an Array using the spread
    // syntax with an Array-literal, and then using Array.prototype.map() to
    // create a new Array based on the contents of the created Array:
    const selectors = [...document.styleSheets].map(
        // here we iterate over the styleSheets, by converting
        // the iterable cssRules property of the styleSheet into an Array
        // (as above), and calling Array.prototype.map() on this nested-
        // Array:
        (style) => [...style.cssRules].map(
          // here we iterate over the cssRules and return a new Array
          // based on the selectorText of the current cssRule:
          (rule) => rule.selectorText
          // here we flatten the multidimensional Array to a one-dimensional
          // Array, using Array.prototype.map(), for easier manipulation later:
        )).flat(),

      // here we take the Array of selectors, and use Array.prototype.filter()
      // to filter the Array, to retain only those that we need:
      themeNumbers = selectors.filter(
        // we pass the current selector into the filter() function, and
        // if the element is truthy (Boolean converts truthy to true, and
        // falsey to false) and also starts with the string "[data-theme="
        // we retain the current element in the Array.
        // (It's worth adding that the use of Boolean() here is only required
        // here on SO, in JS Fiddle it's not required and seems to be due to
        // some cssRules here not having a selectorText, but if it happens
        // here it's probably best to retain it as a safeguard elsewhere):
        (selector) => Boolean(selector) && selector.startsWith("[data-theme=")
        // here we again use Array.prototype.map() to create a new Array based
        // on the contains of the retained elements:
      ).map(
        // again, we pass in the current selector, and here we use
        // String.prototype.match() along with a regular expression literal
        // (delimited by the '/' characters), "\d+", to match a sequence of
        // one or more number characters; that number character is matched
        // and is then passed to parseInt() (along with the radix of 10) to
        // interpret is a number in the decimal base:
        (selector) => parseInt(selector.match(/\d+/), 10)
        // we then use Array.prototype.flat() to ensure a one-dimensional Array:  
      ).flat();

    // we then set the current value to the first element of the Array of
    // numbers derived from the data-theme selectors:
    themedElement.dataset.theme = themeNumbers[0];

    // then we use JSON.stringify to convert the Array of theme numbers
    // into a String that can be stored in the "data-themes" attribute:
    themedElement.dataset.themes = JSON.stringify(themeNumbers);

    // otherwise, if there is a current theme set:
  } else {

    // we increment the currentTheme number after (attribute-values
    // are always Strings) parsing it to a base-10/decimal number:
    const nextNumber = parseInt(currentTheme, 10) + 1;

    // if that nextNumber is included in the values of the possibleThemes
    // Array:
    if (possibleThemes.includes(nextNumber)) {
      // we update the attribute-value of "data-theme" to the nextNumber:
      themedElement.dataset.theme = nextNumber;
      // or, if the nextNumber is not contained within the Array, we:  
    } else {
      // we either set the "data-theme" attribute to the first value
      // of the "data-themes" Array:
      themedElement.dataset.theme = possibleThemes[0];
      // or we could instead simply remove the "data-theme" attribute,
      // since you have default values set in the ":root" element in 
      // the CSS:
      // themedElement.removeAttribute("data-theme");
    }
  }
}

// purely for the demo, we retrieve the <button> that updates the theme settings:
const themeToggle = document.querySelector('button');

// and we then use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the switchTheme() function
// as the event-handler for the 'click' event (but do note the deliberate lack of
// parentheses on the function name):
themeToggle.addEventListener('click', switchTheme);
```

```css
/* Blue */

:root {
  --light: #2874b2;
  --dark: #205d8e;
  --fontLight: #ffffff;
  --fontDark: #205d8e;
}


/* Dark Blue */

[data-theme="1"] {
  --light: #5A7D9F;
  --dark: #3A5874;
  --fontLight: #ffffff;
  --fontDark: #3A5874;
}


/* Pastel Blue */

[data-theme="2"] {
  --light: #709FC1;
  --dark: #48759E;
  --fontLight: #ffffff;
  --fontDark: #48759E;
}


/* Green */

[data-theme="3"] {
  --light: #00e236;
  --dark: #00b52b;
  --fontLight: #ffffff;
  --fontDark: #00b52b;
}


/* irrelevant, just for demo */

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#content {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: var(--light);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: var(--fontLight);
  background-color: var(--dark);
}

button {
  display: block;
  color: var(--fontDark);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <button type="button">Change Theme</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zvL7f28a/).

References:

- [Array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Boolean()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).
- [Conditional ("ternary") Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets).
- [`Element.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).
- [`HTMLOrForeignElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).
- [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).
- [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
- [Logical AND (`&&`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND).
- [Logical NOT (`!`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT).
- [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [Spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- [`StyleSheetList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList).

Comment: Thanks for the code, but i get this error:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at file:///C:/MSFS%20Addons/Tools/gsim-ingamepanels-kneeboard/html_ui/InGamePanels/Kneeboard/Kneeboard.html:600:26
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at switchTheme (file:///C:/MSFS%20Addons/Tools/gsim-ingamepanels-kneeboard/html_ui/InGamePanels/Kneeboard/Kneeboard.html:599:49)
    at HTMLButtonElement.ondblclick (file:///C:/MSFS%20Addons/Tools/gsim-ingamepanels-kneeboard/html_ui/InGamePanels/Kneeboard/Kneeboard.html:34:123)

Comment: Using the same browser does the code work here, and on JS Fiddle? It looks like you're running into JavaScript problems because you're possibly not running your code on a webserver?